# jsoup fetching and displaying table contents in android

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I have a java program which fetches the table contents from [This](http://www.fastvturesults.com/check_new_results/1rn11cs023) link. I want to do the same in android by displaying it in a textview.

Below is my java code

```
public class VtuFetch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.fastvturesults.com/check_new_results/1rn11cs030").
                userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36").get();
        for (Element table : doc.select("table[id=scell]")) {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(0)")) {
               Elements tds = row.select("td:not([rowspan])");
               System.out.println("Semester"+" "+"Attempt"+" "+" "+"Total Marks"+" "+"     Result"+" "+"                          Percentage");
               System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + "        " + tds.get(1).text()+"          "+ tds.get(2).text()+"            "+ tds.get(3).text()+"                              "+ tds.get(4).text());
            }
       }
    }
}
```

Below is my android code which fetches the same link.

```
private class GetMakrs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String desc;
        Elements tds;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.fastvturesults.com/check_new_results/1rn11cs030").
                            userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36")
                            .get();

                                // Using Elements to get the Meta data
                Elements description = doc.select("meta[name=description]");
                for (Element table : doc.select("table[id=scell]")) {
                    for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(0)")) {
                       Elements tds = row.select("td:not([rowspan])");
                       System.out.println("Semester"+" "+"Attempt"+" "+" "+"Total Marks"+" "+"     Result"+" "+"                          Percentage");

                       System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + "        " + tds.get(1).text()+"          "+ tds.get(2).text()+"            "+ tds.get(3).text()+"                              "+ tds.get(4).text());


                    }
               }
                // Locate the content attribute
                desc = description.attr("content");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set description into TextView
            TextView txtdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MarksShow);
            txtdesc.setText(desc);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

I am able to retrive the name of the person, but the table contents are not getting displayed.

**P.S. The java Code works correct, i am having problem porting it to android**

Comment: Post more code of your Android Activity. Any Exceptions / Stack Traces in LogCat ? Do you have internet permission for your app ?

Comment: There are few warn logs and the logcat gets the outputs from system.out.println(i want this output to be show on my textdesc TextView).   and yes i have mentioned the internet permission.The log cat is here pastebin.com/PhVBSnG9

Comment: In your code you are not setting the TextView text with the text you want. Instead of printing the content of the table to `System.out.println(...)`, set it to the textview.

Comment: yes i know, if i try to set my textview to print, then i get a blank textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should set the correct text instead of printing it:

```
private class GetMakrs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String desc = ""; //<-Important!
        Elements tds;

        ...

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                 ...

            Elements description = doc.select("meta[name=description]");
             for (Element table : doc.select("table[id=scell]")) {
                for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(0)")) {
                 Elements tds = row.select("td:not([rowspan])");
                 desc = desc + "Semester"+" "+"Attempt"+" "+" "+"Total Marks"+" "+"     Result"+" "+"                          Percentage";

                 desc = desc + "\n" + tds.get(0).text() + "        " + tds.get(1).text()+"          "+ tds.get(2).text()+"       "+tds.get(3).text()+"      "+ tds.get(4).text();

                 desc = desc + "\n";


                    }
               }
                ...
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set description into TextView
            TextView txtdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MarksShow);
            txtdesc.setText(desc);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yuor code works partially correct, i will post the complete answer in short time.

Comment: i am getting the output, but i am abe to get only the first row of the html document, any idea why is that happening ?

Comment: @penta, You need to use a loop to add all the text to the TextView, will update answer now.

Comment: @penta, Iv'e updated answer, you need to append all the text to the String which you set to textview. Note the changed initialization at the top. Also, you should usually use a `StringBuilder` instead of appending to a String, although it's fine here.